# To use or not use ScrtiptableObects?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Level Prefabs that contain enemies Prefabs inside them. Those Enemy Prefabs contain behavior script components that contain certain values controlling the bevhavior of this specific enemy. **The problem is that those values are almost always unique for every single enemy.**

**Should I use ScriptableObjects in my situation and if yes, then how exactly?**

The reason for my question is that I am totally new to ScriptableObjects so I wanted to ask the experts is there a way to utilize them in this situation, because I want to use the best ways / tools / features for my project right away.

Comment: id have a database of mobs and have scriptable object mob types

Comment: If you don't know how to apply <tool name> to a given problem, then it's the wrong tool for that problem.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post questions on multiple Stack Exchange sites](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/168675/to-use-or-not-use-scriptableobjects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of ScriptableObjects as a C# class with only properties, and no methods.  They are used as a data container that you can assign to game object components through the Unity editor.

In your situation, suppose you have an `EnemyAI` script attached to your Enemy prefab.  Within your `EnemyAI` script, you do something like this

```c#
public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The ScriptableObject asset that is assigned through the Unity editor
    public EnemyInfo enemyInfo;

    private EnemyBehavior currentBehavior;

    void Update()
    { 
        // If this agent has no behavior assigned or it has completed its 
        // previous behavior, choose a new behavior and assign it to this
        // agent
        if (this.currentBehavior == null)
        {
           if (Random.Range(0, 1) <= this.enemyInfo.aggressiveness)
           {
              if (this.enemyInfo.weaponType == "melee")
              {
                 this.currentBehavior = new ChargePlayerBehavior();
              }
              else if (this.enemyInfo.weaponType == "ranged")
              {
                 this.currentBehavior = new ShootPlayerBehavior();
              }
              else
              {
                 throw new Exception("This enemy needs a weapon to attack with!")
              }
           }
           else
           {
              this.currentBehavior = new AvoidPlayerBehavior();
           }
        }

        this.currentBehavior.Update();
    }
}

public class EnemyInfo : ScriptableObject
{
   public float aggressiveness;
   public string weaponType;
   // other fields - max health, speed, etc.
}
```

Then you'd create an `EnemyInfo` asset within your project for each type of enemy behavior.  For instance:

- Sniper who has a ranged weapon and is not very aggressive
- Soldier who has a ranged weapon and is moderately aggressive
- Berserker who has a melee weapon and is very aggressive
- Thief who has no weapon and zero aggression

Then for each enemy prefab you have, you could plug one of those three `EnemyInfo` assets into its `enemyInfo` field, and that'll dictate how the enemy acts.

So, you're basically removing all of the fields that you have on your `EnemyAI` MonoBehaviour (aggressiveness, weapon type, etc.) -- and possibly max health, speed, etc on your main `Enemy` script -- and moving those fields onto a ScriptableObject.  *Or you could create one type of ScriptableObject for enemy AI parameters and one type of ScriptableObject for enemy stats.  That way you can share AI parameters between several enemies that have different stats.*

**Even if your values are unique across all enemies, you're not really losing anything** (except maybe a bit of extra work in creating the ScriptableObject assets).  You're just putting your enemy data fields into your ScriptableObject rather than as fields on your MonoBehaviour.  And you may find in the future that you want to reuse enemy behaviors, such as having a standard soldier and elite soldier that each share the same AI characteristics.

**Advantages**

- If you have several different enemies and you want them to all act as a sniper, you drag the "sniper" asset into their `enemyInfo` field.  Now if you decide that a sniper should be more aggressive, you can change the "sniper" asset's `aggressiveness` in your Unity editor, and it'll apply to all sniper-type enemies.  The alternative would be having to go through each sniper-type enemy individually and change all their aggressivenesses.  Maybe you'll miss a few prefabs or maybe you'll accidentally set different values on different sniper-type enemies.  You can even do this during gameplay testing.
- You can hot-swap enemy behaviors during gameplay by just assigning a different ScriptableObject asset to the enemy in the Unity editor while your game is running.
- If you have several scripts on an enemy that all need access to the same enemy data, you can assign that `EnemyInfo` asset to each script, rather than having several different scripts on the same enemy that all have their own `MaxHealth`, `WeaponType`, etc. fields, or having to have scripts all cross reference each other to access fields.
- You can be part of the ScriptableObjects cool kids club.

[This is a very good presentation on ScriptableObjects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3iHhE_Kk)